# How can I remove elements of a jQuery group that are descendants of other members?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Suppose I've collected a jQuery group of DOM nodes matching some selector, and the selector is such that it's possible that some of the matching nodes might be descendants of other matches, e.g.:

```
<div class="row">
    <!-- ... -->
    <div class="row"><!-- ... --></div>
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
<div class="row">
    <!-- ... -->
    <div class="row">
        <!-- ... -->
        <div class="row"><!-- ... --></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row"><!-- ... --></div>
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

```js
$rows = $('.row');
```

Now suppose that the action I'm going to take will affect each node's entire subtree, and I need to be sure that I act on any given DOM node at most once. How would I remove all elements of my group that are descendants of other members of the same group?

Comment: If the top level `.row` elements are descendant of a common parent use the direct descendant selector: `$('#parent > .row')`

Comment: Sure, in some cases that could work, but I'm more interested in a more general solution that will still work in cases where the DOM may be more scattered and unpredictable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest and cleanest way I've found to accomplish this is to combine the behaviors of `$.fn.not()` and `$.fn.find()`:

```
var $rows = $('.row');
$rows = $rows.not($rows.find($rows));
```

`$elems.find($elems)` will return all members of `$elems` that are descendants of one or more members of `$elems` (not including the element itself, so no worries there). `$elems.not(group)` will return a only the members of `$elems` that are not in `group`. Together, this will find all members of `$elems` that are children of other members, then return everything else.